# Overwrite the default font for Content editor webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I added a content editor webpart in my sharepoint page. By default it is using 'Verdan' font type. How would I change it to 'Arial' ?

Answer (score 1):

Actual class name to overwrite is **ms-WPBody**

Answer (score 0):

The default font settings for the body of a content editor web part are controlled by the

`.ms-rte-wpbox`

style in the corev4.css file.  To change it you will need to override that style with your own CSS

Comment: I tried same like you sugested, but did not get the result. in my custom CSS. in CSS I added `.ms-rte-wpbox{ font-family: Arial; Font Size: 10px}` in designer i added as `<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="CSS Path" After="corev4.css" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>` ... but still not getting the result.. anything I missed

Comment: @ Deep Nair - the class name you suggested was a WRONG ONE and ate a lot of my time.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in response. The `ms-WPBody` would apply styling for any web part in the site. But the class `.ms-rte-wpbox` should be good enough to change the font style for only rich text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

## **Changing the Default Text Style in the Content Editor**

This will change the default font size in the wiki editor on a publishing site.

```
.ms-wikicontent, .ms-wikicontent p, 
.ms-rtestate-field, .ms-rtestate-field p,
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable, .ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable p, 
.ms-rtestate-write, .ms-rtestate-write p{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    color: gray;
}
```

And if you want to change the default style for hyperlinks:

```
.ms-wikicontent a, 
.ms-rtestate-field a,
.ms-rtestate-write a,
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable a{
    color:#2572BC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ms-wikicontent a:hover, 
.ms-rtestate-write a:hover,
.ms-rtestate-field a:hover,
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable a:hover{
    color:#F37B00!important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```