# How to change the default font face and size in the text editor of the ribbon

Tags: 2010, ribbon, rich-text

Is it possible to change the default font face and size in the SharePoint 2010 Rich Text Editor Ribbon control?  If so how?

Note:  I need this to work throughout SharePoint, not just when changing Page Content in a Publishing Page.  I need it to work in Content Editor Web Parts, and other list items with Rich Text fields.

Comment: UPDATE: See related question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32720/overwrite-the-default-font-for-content-editor-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010.  Based on this and some other research I've done, it looks like the "default" styling for any Rich Text Editor is based on the CSS currently being applied to it.  I'll try to update with some examples as time allows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things here:

1) You can override the default fonts.  NothingButSharePoint has a good tutorial: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-font-face-in-Rich-Text-Editor-of-SharePoint-2010.aspx

2) You can use custom Markup Styles: http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/10/27/custom-styles-for-sharepoint-2010-rich-html-field/

Other than that, there really isn't a good way to change the "default" font in the Rich Text Editor.

Comment: The 1st link only shows how to add additional fonts to the end.  The 2nd link  will not work with Content Editor web parts, only publishing pages.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion- I feel if you use for registering font from number -1 to 11 then somewhere it should be able to set it as default font as per the 1st link. Because as mentioned in the blog -1 to 11 are blocked for the defaut fonts. If you override them then you can set your font as default one.